# Not able to decrypt file using openssl

Tags: encryption, openssl

I am trying to decrypt a credentials file given to me by a 3rd party in order to use the credentials by writing it to a .txt file. But unfortunately, I have been receiving errors

I generated a public key and private key using the commands:

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out id_rsa.pem 2048
openssl rsa -in id_rsa.pem -outform PEM -pubout -out id_rsa.pub.pem
```

I sent the public key id_rsa.pub.pem in order to get the encrypted file and received 2 files key.bin.enc and cred_file.enc which were encrypted using the public key I had sent

I was able to generate a key.bin file using the command as shown below:

```
openssl rsautl -decrypt -inkey id_rsa.pem -in key.bin.enc -out key.bin
```

first approach:

```
openssl rsautl -decrypt -inkey id_rsa.pem -in key.bin.enc -out key.bin
Enter pass phrase for id_rsa.pem:
pavanvasan@Pavans-MacBook-Pro ~ % openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -in cred_file.enc -out cred_file.txt -pass file:./key.bin
*** WARNING : deprecated key derivation used.
Using -iter or -pbkdf2 would be better.
bad decrypt
4362464768:error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt:crypto/evp/evp_enc.c:610:
```

alternative method:

```
openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -md md5 -in cred_file.enc -out cred_file.txt 
enter aes-256-cbc decryption password:
* WARNING : deprecated key derivation used.
Using -iter or -pbkdf2 would be better.
bad decrypt
4551466496:error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt:crypto/evp/evp_enc.c:610:
```

My OpenSSL version is OpenSSL 1.1.1m and the 3rd party provider is using OpenSSL version 1.1.1j

what is meant by ***Using -iter or -pbkdf2 would be better***? Is there a way to decrypt the .enc file?
What is it that I am missing here? Please do let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: I would assume that if you get the files from 3rd party then you should also get the exact commands needed to use those files from that 3rd party.

Comment: These were the commands given, as seen below @Robert:
[CMD_1 => openssl rsautl -decrypt -inkey id_rsa.pem -in key.bin.enc -out key.bin]

[CMD_2 => openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -in cred_file.enc -out cred_file.txt -pass file:./key.bin]

The first command succeeded(CMD_1) and I got the key.bin file, but the error is being thrown during the execution of the 2nd command (CMD_2)

Comment: Then communicate that pack to the 3rd party and ask for correct commands.

Comment: I got these commands from the 3rd party team. I am putting these in since even they are not sure what the problem is, after several discussions

Comment: *-iter* or *-pbkdf2* use PBKDF2 as key derivation function instead of the older default (*-iter* can be used to specify PBKDF2 and the iteration count). Since PBKDF2 is more secure, this message is output by default if PBKDF2 is not used. If CMD2 is correct, PBKDF2 is not applied and you can ignore the warning. Check if you use the correct *cred_file.enc* and the correct *key.bin*. Maybe the data is simply inconsistent, i.e. *key.bin.enc* does not contain the (encrypted) key needed to decrypt *cred_file.enc*. Or PBKDF2 is used after all. This must be clarified with the other side.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem gets solved when I used sha256 based on trial and error.
Command I used: `openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -md sha256 -in cred_file.enc -out cred_file.txt`

Comment: Strange. Actually, OpenSSL uses SHA256 by default as of version v1.1.0 (MD5 before that), so this setting should not change anything, at least not for v1.1.1.